Why is does a Vue Router Warning with path /cart.json appear during Nuxt3 setup?
I am setting up a new Nuxt3 project via npm and the project runs with no errors or warnings, but as soon as I create an index.vue page and utilize NuxtPage in app.vue I get the following warning.
[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/cart.json"
I do not have a cart.json file and don't plan to use a json file named that. Has anyone encountered this?

Do you have the issue if you restart the server?

I am using Vite. Yes I still see the error after I enter, npm run dev
